# Performance differences between highp, mediump and lowp

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

I'm in the process of optimizing my shader code for rendering large triangle strips. It has been suggested to me that I should try to use low precision datatypes for my vertex attributes where possible so I started experimenting. I reduced some components from highp to lowp, but didn't get any serious performance improvements. So I used glGetShaderPrecisionFormat to get the ranges and precisions of the formats, however I received the same values for highp, mediump and lowp, that means for example

```
int rangehigh[2], precisionhigh;
glGetShaderPrecisionFormat(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, GL_HIGH_FLOAT, rangehigh, &precisionhigh);

int rangemedium[2], precisionmedium;
glGetShaderPrecisionFormat(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, GL_MEDIUM_FLOAT, rangemedium, &precisionmedium);

int rangelow[2], precisionlow;
glGetShaderPrecisionFormat(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, GL_LOW_FLOAT, rangelow, &precisionlow);
```

that rangehigh/rangemedium/rangelow all have the same values as well as precisionhigh, precisionmedium and precisionlow.

Does this mean that using a mediump or a lowp in place of a highp will not be faster at all?

Regards

Comment: Changing the precision in the shader doesn't do much when it's still stored as 32-bit floating points in memory.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, on your particular device, the same precision will be used regardless of whether you specify lowp, mediump or highp. So you can expect to see no benefit in switching to lower precision on your vertex shader.

To be honest, vertex shader performance is very rarely the performance bottleneck in graphically intensive applications. It's usually fill-rate (i.e. simplify pixel shaders and reduce overdraw) or CPU API overhead (look at reducing draw calls). Occasionally it can be vertex submission (where appropriate, use VBOs, indexed draw calls and reduce the size/improve alignment of the vertices you submit).

It's important to try to establish what the bottleneck is before optimising, else you can expect a lot of efforts to be fruitless.